# Entity Framework query for related table

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I get error

> Invalid column name 'WorkID_Work'

not sure why, can someone please help? Thanks

```cs
var employeeTable = _db.FT_Employee
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(x => x.StartDate >= selectedStartDate 
                                   && x.StartDate <= selectedEndDate
                                   && (x.Work.WorkType == "Remote"))
                       .Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName });
```

```cs
public class FT_Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DM_Work")]
    [Column("ID_Work")]
    public int? ID_Work { get; set; }
    
    public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }
}

public class DM_Work
{
    public int ID_Work { get; set; }
    public string WorkType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added   **[ForeignKey("ID_Work")]** on top of **public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }** issue resolved.

```
 public class FT_Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    
       // [ForeignKey("DM_Work")]
       // [Column("ID_Work")]

        public int? ID_Work { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID_Work")]
        public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `ForeignKey Attribute` but not specifying the relationship between the two entities `FT_Employee` and `DM_Work`. Your code don't tell the system which relationship `one-to-one` or  `one-to-many`.

inside `DM_Work` class, you have to add references to `FT_Employee` class

```
public class FT_Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DM_Work")]
    [Column("ID_Work")]
    public int? ID_Work { get; set; }
    
    public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }
}

public class DM_Work
{
    public int ID_Work { get; set; }
    public string WorkType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FT_Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

### Some more information

Actually, there are 3 ways you can use the `ForeignKey Attribute` to configure the relationship. You can choose one of the below to suite your need

```
// 1. [ForeignKey(NavigationPropertyName)] on the foreign key scalar property
// in the dependent entity. as same as the example above

public class FT_Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DM_Work")]
    [Column("ID_Work")]
    public int? ID_Work { get; set; }
    
    public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }
}

public class DM_Work
{
    public int ID_Work { get; set; }
    public string WorkType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FT_Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

```
// 2. [ForeignKey(ForeignKeyPropertyName)] on the related reference navigation
// property in the dependent entity

public class FT_Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("ID_Work")]
    public int? ID_Work { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ID_Work")]
    public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }
}

public class DM_Work
{
    public int ID_Work { get; set; }
    public string WorkType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FT_Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

```
// 3. [ForeignKey(ForeignKeyPropertyName)] on the navigation property in the
// principal entity

public class FT_Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("ID_Work")]
    public int? ID_Work { get; set; }
    
    public DM_Work Work{ get; set; }
}

public class DM_Work
{
    public int ID_Work { get; set; }
    public string WorkType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID_Work")]
    public ICollection<FT_Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

- More information [Data Annotation - ForeignKey Attributte](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup primary keys properly for your entities and add the missing the `StartDate` property. I have implemented a working example for you below so hopefully it should help you with your issue.

```cs
public class FT_Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int FT_EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public int DM_WorkId { get; set; }
    public DM_Work Work { get; set; }
}

public class DM_Work
{
    [Key]
    public int DM_WorkId { get; set; }
    public string WorkType { get; set; }
}
```

Update your `DbContext` class including seeding data:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<FT_Employee> FT_Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DM_Work> DM_Works { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<DM_Work>()
            .HasData(new DM_Work()
            {
                DM_WorkId = 1,
                WorkType = "Remote"
            },
            new DM_Work()
            {
                DM_WorkId = 2,
                WorkType = "Local"
            });
        
        builder.Entity<FT_Employee>()
            .HasData(new FT_Employee()
            {
                FT_EmployeeId = 1,
                FirstName = "Barry",
                LastName = "Allen",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                DM_WorkId = 1
            },
            new FT_Employee()
            {
                FT_EmployeeId = 2,
                FirstName = "Wally",
                LastName = "West",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
                DM_WorkId = 2
            });
    }
}
```

Run `Migration` and `Update` using `dotnet ef` commands

Querying the employee for selected dates and worktype:

```cs
var selectedStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
var selectedEndDate = DateTime.Now;

var employeeTable = _dbContext.FT_Employee
    .Where(x => x.StartDate >= selectedStartDate 
                && x.StartDate <= selectedEndDate
                && x.Work.WorkType == "Remote")
    .Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName })
    .ToList();

foreach (var table in employeeTable)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{table.FirstName} {table.LastName}");
}
```

Query Output:

```
Barry Allen
```